# HMA41GS6AFR8N-TF 8GB RAM upgrade option

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade

I have Laptop with HMA41GS6AFR8N-TF 8GB RAM i am looking for the upgrade options which ram should I buy.

[image]

Comment: See Super User - [How to find which RAM to get for my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1543730/how-to-find-which-ram-to-get-for-my-computer)

Answer (score 0):

To go to 16GB , just match the part and buy that. It's only $28cdn

Comment: can you pleases share some link

Comment: Keep shopping , wide ranges in price  https://www.ebay.com/itm/125075105001